# Latest Version of BlueSky Textures for Mac

Tags: mac, distributions

I've been a user of Textures since about 1987. I actually used it to prepare my dissertation for a Ph.D. I've continually updated it since and sorry to see it disappear from the scene TEX scene. I currently have a registered version 2.2.0.16b16, but I understand there is a later version (b18) with a few bug fixes. Is there somewhere I can get a copy of the most up-to-date version?

Comment: Please take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108497/what-happened-to-textures-and-bluesky-research/109051#109051

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with it, but my first suggestion to you would be to look at Xe(La)TeX as a replacement, as it has similar support for fonts.  If there are any specific features you are looking for, you should edit them into your question. (And [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436))

Comment: if you wish to follow the discussion proceeding separately, take a look at the archives of the [textures discussion list](https://email.esm.psu.edu/pipermail/textures/) on the mac area of the penn state web site.  as a registered user of textures, you will find information there that isn't of more general applicability.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody asked a few months ago about Textures and Blue Sky Research; see [What happened to Textures and Bluesky Research?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108497/what-happened-to-textures-and-bluesky-research/109051) for details.

As for downloading b18 of the product, the [CNET Downloads page](http://download.cnet.com/Textures/3000-13455_4-37523.html) seems to have what you need. Quoting directly from that page:

> **What's new in version 2.2.0b18**
>
> Some significant bug fixes: A problem with MS-DOS EPSF illustrations was fixed, and the permissible depth of nested folders in the Inputs tree was increased to 99 levels, effectively removing the limit. Also, we fixed a bug that caused a (rare) crash when using Synchronicity on a new Typeset window. (Although very rare, this has by far been the most frequently reported crash in native Textures, i.e., we have had seven reports total.

This version number is accurate; downloading the DMG and inspecting the app, it lists its version as “Textures® version 2.2.0b18”.

I’m not familiar with Textures personally, so I don’t know if this is the final version which was released, but it is a working download of the app. I can’t run the app properly since I don’t have a license, but it does launch and prompt me for a license, so I’d guess this is a legitimate copy.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for. I did read the discussion on Bluesky and am certainly sorry to hear of its demise along with the loss of its founder/programmer.

Comment: Textures is not dead, far from it. The original website www.bluesky.com is no longer available. After a catastrophic failure that took down everything at the time of my husband's death we have been working frantically to piece together the files and documentation that we could save and we are now in the process to move everything to www.blueskytex.com. If anyone would like any information or have any questions for which I may have the answer, please contact me at president@blueskytex.com