# Is there a substitute for Blue Sky's TeXtures?

Tags: editors

Is there a substitute for Blue Sky's TeXtures program? That is, some other TeX editor that typesets TeX code in real time?

Comment: [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/)..?  Or: what do you mean by 'in real time'?

Comment: LyX doesn't compile in real time. [Gummi](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org) does compile as you type, but how this compares with Textures I don't know, having never used the latter.

Comment: There is Claus Gerhardt's Flashmode script for TeXShop: http://www.math.uni-heidelberg.de/studinfo/gerhardt/Flashmode/ (never tried it myself).

Comment: Kile to compiles in real time.

Comment: Other questions about that software (it doesn’t have its own tag): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108497/what-happened-to-textures-and-bluesky-research, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121590/latest-version-of-bluesky-textures-for-mac

Answer (score 2):

[BaKoMa TeX Word](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/) is one which typesets on-line.
It is new under Mac (first release Sep/2011), but mature under Windows (Jan/2005). (This is a commercial product, like Textures, and has a one month trial version available.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! No link? No trial version? No notice that it's commercial?

Comment: it’s mentioned in the uk faq (label syswin32); the specs look good ... so sort of stealth advertisement...