# In Textures, is there a way to permanently increase the size of the font used for displaying the TeX file?

Tags: editors, mac

In Textures, is there a way to permanently increase the size of the font used for displaying the TeX file?  Or is there another way of increasing the font size?

Comment: What is Textures, is it an editor?

Comment: @Aradnix A dinosaur, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108497/what-happened-to-textures-and-bluesky-research

Comment: @Alex I don't think that it's a dinosaur. I read that question and the sad story behind that editor. Also good comments about it. The [website](http://www.blueskytex.com/) announces news for October of this year.

Comment: @Aradnix Sure, it's a sad story. They should have open-sourced it. The last time I've seen people using Textures was several years ago. Makes it hard to answer the original question...

Comment: @Alex That's right... we'll see if TeXtures becomes open sourced or what happen with it in October, for now is hard to reply this question.

Answer (score 1):

In the Terminal, say

```
defaults write com.bluesky.Textures TextFontSize 16
```

or equivalent.