# Knuth “Some Implementations of TeX”…

Tags: tex-core

In Appendix D of *The TeXBook*, p. 387, in a discussion about automatic column sizing, Knuth tantalizes us with this:

> Some implementations of TeX display the output as you are running, so that you can choose column widths interactively until a suitable balance is obtained.

What are these other “implementations” of TeX? Are they moribund or do they still exist?

Comment: Predecessors of LyX perhaps?

Comment: This is more a question of history for me, especially because it's my understanding of TeX itself I want to refine for its own sake. The modern systems are mostly geared toward LaTeX rather than the fundamentals.

Comment: Systems which use Unix IPC (Inter Process Communication) are able to do something of this sort (e.g., TeXview.app on NeXTstep). I suspect that Dr. Knuth was talking about systems running on one of the large computer systems which he used at Sanford though.

Comment: @WillAdams -- the "large computer systems at stanford" were sail (a decsystem 10) and score (a decsystem 20).  neither of them *ever* had an "interactive" mode.  (knuth didn't feel the need, i think.)  first implementation was on an early mac -- textures, as identified in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Textures was such an implementation, on Mac OS, and it was created in the mid eighties. It had a “Flash Mode” feature which worked exactly as Knuth describes in the TeXbook. I suppose Knuth was referring to Textures among others. It has been extant until a couple of years ago. Since then, I've got no news about it…

[What happened to Textures and Bluesky Research?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108497/what-happened-to-textures-and-bluesky-research/109051#109051)

On Mac OS X, Claus Gerhardt's Flashmode allows this feature on [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/). (I've not tested it yet, but others do use it and it seems to work well.)

http://www.math.uni-heidelberg.de/studinfo/gerhardt/Flashmode/

**Edit** As indicated in the previous link about Textures, there is a new site dedicated to it: http://www.blueskytex.com. It provides a (free) download link to a no longer developed beta version for Mac OS X. More news are promised for soon (2015 July 1).