# Why cmmib10 font is not available in stripped down versions of TeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, tex-history

In TeXbook p.156 it is said:

> Suppose that you want to extend plain TEX by putting
>   boldface math italic letters in family 9, analogous to the normal math italic letters
>   in family 1. (Such fonts aren’t available in stripped down versions of TEX, but let’s
>   assume that they exist.)

`plain.tex` contains this:

```
\font\preloaded=cmmib10 % bold math italic
```

Considering the fact that `plain.tex` cannot be changed, I don't understand how (and why) this font may not be available in some versions of TeX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knuth “Some Implementations of TeX”…](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250878/knuth-some-implementations-of-tex)

Comment: @HenriMenke The question was asked because the last sentence in this quote from TeXbook is rather confusing. I don't see the point: why "such" fonts may not be available, and "normal math italic" **must** be available? Therefore, the link that you provided does not answer my question at all.

Comment: The point I wanted to make by marking this a duplicate is that such a stripped down version of TeX does not exist, but Knuth assumed that there potentially *could* exist such a version.  And since bold math italics are not too essential for typesetting a hypothetical stripped down version could leave these out.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think this note is no good. Do you think this note would better be removed, or replaced with "(This font is called cmmib10.)"?

Comment: @HenriMenke Also, it is not clear what is "version of TeX". Is it "implementation of TeX" or "distribution of TeX"?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. For one thing, not only does the sole answer at the linked question not answer *this* question, it does not even answer *that* question fully.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Ah, I was waiting for you to show up.  I'm looking forward to your well-research answer about TeX history to this question ;) I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @HenriMenke Unfortunately I know nothing about this one here :-) Maybe this line was written for some earlier version of The TeXbook and not updated; someone may know...

Comment: BTW I still don't understand why 4 people have voted to close this as duplicate of [Knuth “Some Implementations of TeX”…](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250878/knuth-some-implementations-of-tex). That question asks which TeX implementations display the output continuously (what we might call “live preview”), so that for example you can choose column widths interactively. (Those implementations therefore have *more* features than standard TeX.) This question asks why stripped-down versions of TeX are allowed not to include cmmib10. What is the connection between the two questions??

Comment: @ShreevatsaR see https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-k/2019-July/003033.html and https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-k/2019-July/003034.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the context I think it is clear that it means (what we would now call) a stripped down *distribution* of tex rather than an *implementation* of tex.

Note that your statement

> Considering the fact that plain.tex cannot be changed

isn't accurate: `plain.tex` says you can change this bit of the file

> % (And those that were \preloaded above can be eliminated.)

and the equivalent section of appendix B of the TeXBook is more explicit on this point

> The `plain.tex` files used on different machines
>   can be expected to differ widely with respect to preloaded fonts,
>   since the choice of how many fonts to preload and the selection of the
>   most important fonts depends on local conditions.